# Upgrading django from 1.9 to 1.11: reverse accessor clash

Tags: python, django

models.py:

```
class Societe(models.Model):
    ...

class Client(Societe):
    ...
    class Meta(Societe.Meta):
        proxy = True

class Fournisseur(Societe):
    ...
    class Meta(Societe.Meta):
        proxy = True

class Commande(models.Model):
    Client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='Commandes')
    Fournisseur = models.ForeignKey(Fournisseur, related_name='Commandes')
```

This works in Django 1.9, but in 1.11, I get the error:

```
Commande.Client: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Commande.Client' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Commande.Fournisseur'.
Commande.Client: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Commande.Client' clashes with reverse query name for 'Commande.Fournisseur'.
Commande.Fournisseur: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Commande.Fournisseur' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Commande.Client'.
Commande.Fournisseur: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Commande.Fournisseur' clashes with reverse query name for 'Commande.Client'.
```

Django seems to consider that `Client` and `Fournisseur` are the same model.
I dont't want to change related names, any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: why don't you want to change the related_name?. You will get conflict in the future calling foreign key

Comment: Which conflict? Why? I use this app since years!